# Post API request in R

Tags: r, api, post

I want to use textrazor RET API in R (https://www.textrazor.com/docs/rest).

code bellow return 400 status and error

No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.

```
[1] "{\"ok\":false, \"time\":0, \"error\":\"Please provide a TextRazor API Key in either the X-TextRazor-Key header, or apiKey POST Param\"}\n"
```

My code :

```
base <- "http://api.textrazor.com/"
tekst <- "Stagnacja, znużenie i brak możliwości rozwoju działają frustrująco."
pobranie_api7 <- POST(url=base,extractors="words", text=tekst)
```

Comment: Your error message says you need to supply an API key. Have you done this?

Comment: I have done this. I need to build header of request. At this moment i am trying to build request body.